# I have a 2009 Honda Accord 2.4 and I replaced the battery and alternator and the car will not keep running. Its not holding a charge

Tags: battery, alternator

Hello my 2009 Honda Accord won't seem to stay running after I replaced the battery and the alternator. We took the battery and alternator to get it tested and is still good, so I was wondering what could be the issue? Could it be a relay or fuse?

Comment: How long does your car run for? You mention it does not hold a charge, have you checked the battery voltage? When you start the car and turn the key to the accessory position (notch before starting the car) do you hear the fuel pump running?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

The reason: it's not be running for very long. It could be the gasket between the throttle body and the intake manifold, or between the manifold and engine block. Also I would check the vacuum lines for cracks.

I'd also do what @MJH mentioned and checked to see if you could hear the fuel pump.